# Fast long calculation

Tags: hash, polynomials, polynomial-math

I have the following task.

I have 1 billion or more 20-bytes distinct hashes (stored in some database) which total number
is less than Java's `Long.MAX_VALUE;`

After that I have almost infinite stream of such hashes.

Is there possibility to create some bijective mapping from the set of these 20-bytes distinct hashes
to the set of numbers between 0 and `Long.MAX_VALUE` ?

Kind of Lagrange polynomial calculation - but may be there is something really fast and effective for such case.

We need fast `long` value calculation for each hash from this almost infinite stream.

Each 20 - bytes hash is just a number.

Before stream's processing we can create mapping

```
  20-byte | 8-byte
    (hash1 1) 
    .... 
    (hashN N)
```

After that when we have next hash from the infinite stream we will obtain 8-byte hash value without lookups using only arithmetical calculations.

Comment: Are you really asking if you can hash the 20-byte hash value down to a *unique* 8-byte hash value?

Comment: like it is described here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial.



Kind of hash but without collisions.

Comment: So this is not a hash.

We can construct mapping in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Could you add some examples to make it a little less abstract?

Comment: Hash aNextHash = Stream.getHash();

long aValue = calculateLong(aNextHash);

How should I obtain aValue here avoiding lookups to the database or index ?

Comment: if you can construct the mapping in advance and amount of your hashes < long MAX_VALUE, then just put them in defined order and count  through. to convert between long and hash you have to do lookup (probably in memory).

Comment: Count through billions for the stream with high frequency ?

Comment: --to do lookup (probably in memory)

The question is - how to avoid lookups.

Comment: *"we will obtain 8-byte hash value without lookups using only arithmetical calculations"* You cannot calculate a **unique** 8-byte value from a 20-byte value, when the 20-byte value is itself a hash, i.e. it is already using the full range of the 20-byte number-space.

Comment: Really ? why ?
For example I can construct Lagrange polynomial and it will work.

But it will not be effecient.

Comment: And the number of hashes is less than Long.MAX_VALUE

Comment: How would you solve your problem with a Lagrange polynomial? @AVT

Comment: Lagrange polynomial returns exactly that long point for that specific input 20-bytes number, because we construct it using this pre-defined polynomial's values

Comment: Lagrange polynomial is just an example. It is very difficult to use it and non effecient.

Comment: It's hard to imagine how you could make a Lagrange polynomial work here. What you're looking for is something like a [perfect hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function), but that's lookup-based and requires O(n) space.

Comment: What about Fast Fourier Transformation in Finite Fields ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you gave no practical constraints on size or storage beyond "It has to be fast", I am going to assume you can take your time to pre-process the set of hashes in order to "make it fast". I am further assuming the hashes are distributed randomly and that the mapping to 8-byte numbers is likewise unpredictable.

My first approach would be a local SQLite database. That allows you to use its native BTree indexing to quickly retrieve results. With a large enough page size you can store 256 pointers per BTree node for an expected amount of log_256(10^9)= 3.737169106748283 disk seeks per lookup. This will improve as more of your BTree structures get cached.

Second approach, if you have the memory for it: in-memory BTree.

Comment: This is again solution with lookups.

The question is about Mathematical approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Would it work something like this?

```
aNextHash = Stream.getHash();
long aValue = aNextHash % Long.MAX_VALUE;
```

Comment: Yes, but modular doesn't work here
We need another function